# Why i can't submit my form with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a drag and drop component and i try to submit my form with javascript, but when i hit submit the page don't reload.

```
<form class="ddf" action="url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="upload-file" name="featured_image" accept="image/*">
//others input
</form>
```

My script:

```
<script>
        var form = document.getElementsByClassName('ddf')[0];
        var ddfObj = new Ddf({
            element: form,
            maxFiles: 1
        });
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event){
            // my form has been submitted
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(form); // form data in a set of key/value pairs that you can pass to your backend
            for(var i = 0; i < ddfObj.droppedFiles.length; i++) {
                // store selected files
                formData.append('featured_image', ddfObj.droppedFiles[i]);
            }

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    // success
                }
            };

            xhttp.open("POST", '{{ route('admin::categories.store') }}');
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('x-csrf-token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            xhttp.send(formData);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is your submit button? can you add that to the question?

Comment: When you do `event.preventDefault();` on the submit event, you stop the default form submission

Comment: @agrm That would reload the page. He wants to send AJAX. I can see he is using jQuery but he does not utilize the AJAX functionality in it.

Comment: I thought he wanted the page to reload. After all his question is _"but when i hit submit the page don't reload"_.

Comment: If he wants to reload the page then he does not need JS. He can just use forms as they are. Yes, the question is a bit confusing.

Comment: I think the question lacks clarity about the reload thing plus he is using jQuery and yet he is using vanilla JS for the posting the images.

Comment: what i'm using here is a drag and drop component where i upload a file, so when i submit the form i need to store the selected file in a set of key/value pairs so i can pass the formData.

Comment: i use. this component https://codyhouse.co/ds/components/app/drag-drop-file

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
const fileInput = document.querySelector("#upload-file");

const uploadFile = files => {
  console.log("Uploading file...");
  const API_ENDPOINT = "https://localhost/imgHandler";
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  const formData = new FormData();

  request.open("POST", API_ENDPOINT, true);
  request.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      console.log(request.responseText);
    }
  };
  files.forEach(file=>{
       formData.append("file", file);
  })
  request.send(formData);
};

fileInput.addEventListener("change", event => {
  const files = event.target.files;
  uploadFile(files);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the below line

```
    xhttp.open("POST", '{{ route('admin::categories.store') }}');
```

The correct one is below.

```
   xhttp.open("POST", '{{ route("admin::categories.store") }}');
```